# Erro ao tentar fazer upload de imagem no fire base com flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou tentando lançar uma imagem no storage do fire base
mas a seguinte mensagem aparece
Unhandled Exception: type 'XFile' is not a subtype of type 'File' in type cast
esse é o codigo:

```
 IconButton(
              onPressed: () async{
                final File? imgFile = (await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)) as File;
                if(imgFile == null){
                  return;
                }
                else{
                  widget.enviarMensagem(imgFile: imgFile);
                }
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
          ),
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Pela documentação e exemplos apresentados pelo [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker), o retorno é um `XFile` e não um `File` (`dart:io`), consequentemente não é possível fazer a conversão da forma que está fazendo. Se precisa mesmo de um `File`, pode criá-lo utilizando o atributo [`XFile.path`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cross_file/latest/cross_file/XFile/path.html):

```
final XFile? imgFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

// supondo que 'imgFile' não é nulo aqui.
final File file = File(imgFile.path);
```

Comment: muito obrigado!!